# Captive Portal Blocking Attached Files

Tags: squid

We're using Alcasar captive portal, which is using Squid 3 for web caching and DansGuardian for web filtering ... everything works fine except for the upload matters, such as attaching files in mails, gmail, yahoo ... none works !

When attach a file, it just hangs and keeps loading forever, no matter what the size or the type of the object attached !

We the think its Squid behind this, but it could be DansGuardian, or even Chilli the captive portail !

Whats the troubleshooting for this kind of problems ? Anyone had this issue before ?

Thanks !

Comment: You'll likely need to perform packet captures to diagnose this. There's no where near enough data here for any of us to help you at the moment.

Comment: Ok I'm using wireshark for packet captures, what information should I look for while intercepting the packets ?